# Keep ratio of DIV or img

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to keep the ratio of DIV
For example
I use google map

`<div id="map" style="background-color: grey;width:100%;"> Map here </div>`

It adjust the width to window or `col-*` for `bootstrap`.

it changes according to window size.

But now I want to keep the width:height ratio = 1 : 1

How should I do??

Same situation happens to `img`

I want to keep this img square

`<img class="img-fluid" style="width:100%;">`

Comment: Taka a look at this https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aspect ration css for maintening width and height eqauls.
See below code and see **[Aspect Ratio](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)** for more information

```css
.div {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map" class="div" style="background-color: grey;width:100%;"> Map here </div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works well for my code. Thanks to your explanation, easy to understand.